# How can I find the order of growth?

Tags: summation, computer-science

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i2^{n+1}$$

Is it $\Theta(n^2)$ as the $2^{n+1}$ is a constant so it will drop out and it will be only $i$ which is $\cfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by omega here, but it is true that $\sum_{i=1}^n i\times 2^{n+1}=2^{n+1}\times \sum_{i=1}^n i=2^{n+1}\times \frac {n(n+1)}2$.

Comment: i mean Θ(n^2) which describes the order of growth of the sum above

Comment: $\Theta$ it is called *theta*.

Comment: Ah.  That is a capital theta, not omega.

Comment: For what it is worth,  there is an asymptotic  notion of $f(x)=\Omega (g(x))$ but I don't believe there is a clear consensus on what it means.  The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) gives two different definitions for it.

Comment: In your case, of course, the $2^{n+1}$ dominates $n^2$ by rather a lot.  So you can say $f(n)=\Theta \left(n^2\,2^{n+1}\right)$ if you like.

Comment: @lulu $f(n)\sim n^2\,2^{n}$ could be simpler and more helpful as the  actual answer is $n^2\,2^{n}+n2^{n}$

Comment: Wouldn't we just write $f(n)\in\Theta(2^n)$?

Comment: @Math1000 No - because $f(n)/2^n > n^2 \to \infty$

Comment: Oh wait, never mind. I forgot that it is a product and not a sum :)

Comment: So, anybody want to write up and post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out in the comments, $$f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^ni2^{n+1}=n^22^n+n2^n$$ so $f(n)$ is asymptotic to $n^22^n$.